# NReco PDF Generator overlapping table header when the table is split over pages

Tags: pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using NReco PDFGenerator to create a PDF document from an HTML string. When a table is split over a page break, the table header overlaps the next row in the table (see image below).

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: can you show you setting how you can show page number at bottom, as I have to display page header as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found that this is fixed by adding the following css:

```
thead {display: table-header-group;}
tfoot {display: table-row-group;}
tr {page-break-inside: avoid;}
```

Comment: This worked for me too and, it made it so the table header repeated on the continuation page.  Nice implementation.